# What is the SSIS OLE DB COMMAND Escape Character for a single quote?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019

I am trying to run an expression that has single quotes and parameters and I am not having success. From what I've seen, my problem seems to be the escape character. Can you explain me how to write the expression that will result in the appropriate SQL query with single quotes?

Desired result:
`UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1 = 789 WHERE COLUMN2 = '123456';`

Current command I am trying:
`UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1 = ? WHERE COLUMN2 = \'?\';`

Comment: There is no need to escape or enclosed parameterized values. Your current command should be `UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1 = ? WHERE COLUMN2 = ?`

Comment: @DanGuzman I need to escapre the single quotes around the 2nd parameter, not the parametre itself.

Comment: @pedrof, do not enclose parameters in quotes. See the code in my comment and read [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).